# jQuery click event not working IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events, click

The following code in IE7 or IE8 doesn't work. Is this a bug? It works fine in IE6 (Incredible!)

http://jsfiddle.net/zgSmT/

Comment: This works for me in IE7 and IE8. Have you brought up the developer panel in IE8 and tried to debug the JS?

Comment: I'm using ietester so maybe that's why...

Comment: Yeah, I was directly in the browser and it worked perfectly... I used IE7, IE7 Quriks mode, IE8 Standard, and IE8 Quirks... weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the `live` event, or binding the event after `document` load:

```
$('#clickme').live('click', function(){
    alert('hey');
});
```

Also, you're still loading `scripts.js`, which doesn't exist, in your fiddle example - that might also cause a problem.

Comment: Nop! This is still not working. This is driving me crazy! I updated the code here http://jsfiddle.net/zgSmT/4/. Any other ideas?

Comment: Live is really only good if you are adding the same event to a bunch of different objects. If you only have one object, then adding the event listener with click is the same thing.

Comment: I think this might be an IETester problem - it works for me in IE7 and IE8.

Comment: @El Guapo: No, `live` ensures that even if a element matched by the selector is created (added to the DOM) after the javascript is executed, the event will still be bound. With `click`, the event will only be bound if the element already exists in the DOM.

Comment: Very true... good point!!! I gave you a "up" for that. I forgot about that feature of 'live'. :)

Comment: Ok, so it must be a ietester bug. I installed ie9 on my system and now the only way to test these things are ietester or a virtual machine so I'm gonna have to go with the VM.

Comment: Wish I found this answer an hour ago. Also wish I could give you more up votes. Really saved me on this one. Damn old IEs

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
$().ready(function ()
{
    $('#clickme').live('click', function(){
        alert('hey');
    });
}
```

To ensure everything is loaded.