# JQuery not working in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have been given the following code to implement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hotspots a').bind('mouseover click', function() {
      $this = $(this);
      if($('.hotspot-target').data('hotspot')!=$this.attr('href')) {
        $('.hotspot-target').data('hotspot', $this.attr('href'));

        $('.hotspot-target').fadeOut(100, function() {
          $('.hotspot-target').css({backgroundImage: 'url('+$this.attr('href')+')'});
          $('.hotspot-target .detail').hide();
          $('.hotspot-target .detail.'+$this.attr('class')).show();

          $('.hotspot-target').fadeIn(100);
        });
      }
      return false;
    })
  });
</script>
```

It works fine in FF and Chrome with no errors in the console.
I also can't see any errors in the IE debugger, though I'm not so used to how that works.

Is there anything obviously wrong with the above code?
It's placed at the end of the page

Comment: there is an issue with IE7 and IE8 (not IE6!) regarding attached 'click' and 'change' events. You could use `mousedown` or `mouseup` events instead of `click`.

Comment: dont forget to use var on your variables, you should also look into cache the $('.hotspot-target') there is no need to find it 3 times when you can just do it once.

Comment: @AlexanderV.B. what is this bug? what version? have never had any problems with the `click` event in IE before.

Comment: @voigtan, I had such problems. Others also. take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821501/jquery-click-event-not-working-ie7-and-ie8)

Comment: that probably happens because I attached live events(with `.on()`) outside the `$(document).ready()` block. :) But I'm not sure util I test.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried removing the click and replacing it with mousedown but it didnt make any difference.

I'm quite new to JQuery and didnt write this code. I just need to get it working asap, otherwise I may have to attempt to rewrite it (which will take ages for me!)

Maybe I will try replacing the href with a class and put the image in the css

Comment: The html bit is here:    <div class="hotspots">
          <a href="assets/images/bags/hotspot-1.jpg" class="hotspot-1"></a>
          <a href="assets/images/bags/hotspot-2.jpg" class="hotspot-3"></a>
          <a href="assets/images/bags/hotspot-3.jpg" class="hotspot-2"></a>
        </div>

Comment: I think it would be better if I could dynamically add a class to .hotspot-target rather than use the href. Really struggling with this though..

Comment: @user1665283 check the answer below, what version of jQuery are you using? Could you add an example on for example jsfiddle that show us your problem?

Comment: I think it actually might be an obscure bug with position:absolute and the anchor. I have it working in IE now but the link only works if I add a border (and then only the 1px border hovers a cursor:pointer, the centre does not). The anchor has width, height, display:block. God damn IE!

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hotspots a').bind('mouseover click', function() {
        var hotSpotTarget = $('.hotspot-target'),
            value = this.href,
            cssClass = this.className;

        if(hotSpotTarget.data('hotspot') != value) {
            hotSpotTarget.data('hotspot', value);

            hotSpotTarget.fadeOut(100, function() {
                hotSpotTarget.css('background-image', 'url(' + value+ ')');
                hotSpotTarget.find('.detail').hide().filter('.' + cssClass).show();
                hotSpotTarget.fadeIn(100);
            });
        }
        return false;
    })
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2F9VW/1/